# How to insert into multiple postgres tables connected with foreign keys in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to insert into two tables - one table is Invoices, other one is products. Invoice table connected to product table with `product_id` fk. An invoice can have multiple products at the same time and invoice detail and product details shall be inserted at the same time (there is no existing product on Products table) so I have to models:

```py
    class Invoice(models.Model):
        ...
        product = model.Foreignkey(Products,
                                   releted_name="invoice_product", 
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        ...

    class Products(models.Model):
        id = models.Charfield()
        name = models.Charfield()
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create nested serializers.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        product_data = validated_data.pop('product')
        product = Products.objects.create( **product_data)
        invoice = Invoice.objects.create(product=product, **validated_data)
        return invoice
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

In your **views.py** you can just use a **modelviewset** to do all CRUD method:

```
from rest_framework import status, viewsets
from serializers import InvoiceSerializer

class InvoiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing Invoices.
    """
    queryset = Invoice.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvoiceSerializer
```

Last but not least you need to add it to your **urls.py**:

```
invoice_list = InvoiceViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})

invoice_detail = InvoiceViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})

urlpatterns = [ 
                  path('api/invoice/', invoice_list, name='invoice-view'),
                  path('api/invoice/<int:pk>/', invoice_detail, name='invoice-detail'),...]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Django's transcation.atomic context-manager to do that

You can follow the following link for more:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

```
with transaction.atomic():
        # This code executes inside a transaction.
        obj1 = Invoice(product=product_object)
        obj2 = Products(name="anyname")

        obj1.save()
        obj2.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may insert the products and invoices in an atomic transaction

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    product = Product(name="Product Name")
    product.save()
    invoice1 = Invoice(product=product)
    invoice1.save()
    invoice2 = Invoice(product=product)
    invoice2.save()
```